# JQuery toggle Register multible divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have the following problem.

I have a register which is on the right side of the page. It has a button at the end and if you click on the button the register should toogle to the screen and if you click again, it should be hidden again.

This is my current solution:

jsfiddle.net/6JLr9/

(Button: green, Content: red

My problem here is: During the hiding and showing animation, the button doesn't move, when the animation is finished, the button is directly moved to the new (correct) position. How can I make the button move at the same time?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmmdV/).
Changed a few things in js and css.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('.registers').click(
        function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('open')){
                $('.registers-wrapper').animate({'margin-left':'-33px'},1000);
                $(this).removeClass('open');
            }else{
                $('.registers-wrapper').animate({'margin-left':'-233px'},1000);
                $(this).addClass('open');
            }         
        })
}
);
```

CSS:

```
.registers {
width:33px;
height:136px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
float:left;
z-index:50;
}

.registers-content {
height:136px;
width:200px;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-color:red;
float:left;
z-index:50;
}

.registers-wrapper {
  position:fixed;
  left:100%;
  z-index:50;
    margin-left:-33px;
    width:233px;
}



.videohilfe-wrapper {
top:160px;
}
.videohilfe {
background-color:green;
}
.videohilfe-content {
}
```

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some change in Javascript and CSS. Here are the changes

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('.videohilfe').click(function(){
               if($('.videohilfe-wrapper').css('right') == '-200px')
                    $('.videohilfe-wrapper').animate({right:'0px'});
               else
                    $('.videohilfe-wrapper').animate({right:'-200px'});
            });
        }
    );
```

CSS :

```
.registers-wrapper {
  position:fixed;
  right:-200px;  /* changed */
  z-index:50;
}
```